# Probability based problem for machine learning.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image]

See this is the question and the output of it is given as this

### Input

0.2
0.2
0.5

### output

0.160000

I am trying to learn machine learning I have to code program based on this But the problem is that I can't understand this can anyone help me with this ?

Coding part is no problem but I have no understanding whatsoever about this have learned about probability but not this type of problems .This is not a home work or figure yourself question which I am posting here .For most the coding part is the issue for me I have issue with this thing ,it's a self learning course where either  you get program right or wrong no other response so,if I need to write the program I need to understand how to solve this problem.

I foud the answer to this question to be this

**p= p1*(pab(1-pmb) + pmb(1-pab))**
I can easily write code for it but can you explain to me  in detail what I understood is probability to rain X(sum of individual probabilities of not bumping into each other)

### Code

```
a = input("Hello enter Pmb , Pab and P1").split()

a=[ float(i)for i in a]



print(a)

d=a[2]*((a[0]*(1-a[1]))+((1-a[0])*a[1]))
print(d)
```

Comment: i don't understand what this has to do with Machine Learning.  Seems like a straight forward probability question (for which you already have the answer). Am I missing something?

Comment: This was the basic thing to do before they go into machine learning so a probability problem and the code to generate answer for different inputs .I wanted some one to explain to me about the answer and if I am understanding right

Comment: Ok, well in order for them to meet first in the rain it is necessary that it rain ($p_1$) AND it is necessary that one take the bus and the other not.  The probability that mike takes the bus and alice doesn't is $p_{mb}\times (1-p_{ab})$ and the other factor is similar.

Comment: If the coding is not at issue, then maybe you could have asked the question more clearly without including coding.

Comment: @BrueET i have given it because due to my past bitter experiences with stackexchange many a times when I actually wanted to know something people without paying attention to the post just down vote or flag citing this as homework or something similar which was in fact not the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do it for $p_1 = 1/5$ and $p_{mb} = p_{ab} = 1/2.$ [For example, each person tosses a fair coin to decide whether to take the Bus (Heads) or the train (Tails).]

(a) $P(\text{Both take bus}) = (1/2)^2.$ [HH.]

(b) $P(\text{Different modes of travel}) = 2(1/2)^2 = 1/2.$ [HT or TH.]

(c) $P(\text{Different modes} \cap {Rain}) = P(\text{Different modes})P(\text{Rain}) = (1/2)(1/5) = 1/10.$ [The symbol $\cap$ means 'and'.]

All three answers use Independence (to multiply). Equation (b)
uses the Addition Rule for Disjoint Events (to add $1/4 + 1/4 = 1/2).$

If you don't know about independence and adding probabilities of disjoint events, it is time to read your text
carefully or to seek out a basic probability text. Now, I hope you can do
the more general case, in which $p_{mb} \ne p_{ab},$ so that (b) is just a little
more difficult--as in the excellent clue from @lulu.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I figured it before